# Improving finding null in array and inserting there

Tags: java, arrays, object

In this task I have to practice the interaction of all components I have to know so far. This includes objects, control structures (if, for) and arrays. I have to implement a `Workshop` class which is intended to simulate a workshop. The workshop has a limited number of spaces for cars. The places are given with the array cars.

By means of the method `acceptCar`, other objects from the outside (e.g. persons) are to give cars to the workshop for repair. The workshop should only accept cars if there is a free space in the workshop and the car is actually damaged. If the car is accepted, it must be placed in one of the free spaces of the variable cars and the method returns true. If, on the other hand, the car is not accepted, the return value should be false and nothing else should happen.

Here is my solution for this task. I got it right, but I don't fully understand the code, and I'm unsure if this is efficient at all. The code is written in Java.

```java
// Aufgabe 2
public boolean acceptCar(Car car){
    int  autos = 0;
    boolean end = true;
    for(int i = 0;i<this.cars.length;i++) {
        if(cars[i]!=null) {
            autos++;
        }
    }
    if(autos<cars.length&&car.isDamaged() == true) {
        cars[autos] = car;
        end = true;
    }
    else {
        end = false;
    }
    return end;
}
```

Comment: If the array `cars` contains a null element in the middle (followed by non-null elements) then you risk overwriting an element that already has a car with the new car.

Comment: @k314159 What do you mean? The insertion point `autos` seems to be computed correctly and not offset-by-one, no?

Comment: @Zabuzard it counts the number of non-nulls, it doesn't find the first null. This works ok assuming `acceptCar` is the only thing writing to the array; but it might be better simply to find the first null.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple smaller improvements that can be made to this method.

---

### Damage-check first

First of all, no matter what, if the given `car` is **damaged**, you will not insert anything. So why not check that directly at the beginning:

```
if (car.isDamaged()) {
    return false;
}
```

---

### Remembering `i`

Next, you are searching for the first spot in `cars` which is `null` in order to put the car there.

While, from a complexity perspective, you **can not improve performance** here anymore (such an approach will always be `O(n)`), you can significantly **improve readability** by keeping the index `i` alive outside of the loop:

```
if (car.isDamaged()) {
    return false;
}

int i = 0;
for (; i < cars.length; i++) {
    if (cars[i] == null) {
        break;
    }
}

if (i == cars.length) {
    return false;
}

cars[i] = car;
return true;
```

---

### Helper method, `OptionalInt`

Additionally, you could move the *search-part* out into a helper method to increase the readability further:

```
private static <E> OptionalInt indexOf(E[] elements, E element) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (Objects.equals(elements[i], element)) {
            return OptionalInt.of(i);
        }
    }
    return OptionalInt.empty();
}
```

And then use that method in your code instead:

```
if (car.isDamaged()) {
    return false;
}

OptionalInt index = indexOf(cars, null);
if (!index.isPresent()) {
    return false;
}

cars[index.orElseThrow()] = car;
return true;
```

---

### Changes to the workshop

That said, you might be able to change the whole `cars` system to a system that **knows its free spots** and has direct access to them. For example a bounded `Queue<Car>` or similar instead of an array `Car[]` that is filled with `null` to indicate availability.

That would significantly boost the performance of this method from `O(n)` to `O(1)`.

Comment: In theory, great advice. But for a student who states "_[...]i have know so far. This includes objects, control structures (if, for) and arrays"_ and "_but i don't fully understand the code_", this is probably a bit too sophisticated. After all, this is an assignment.

Comment: @maloomeister Agreed, hence your answer is there to the rescue. Note however that answers on SO are also supposed to account for future visitors of the same or similar question. So I guess having both answers completement each other very well :)

Comment: @JeffHolt Good spot, fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good, but there are a few things that could be improved.

1. If you found an empty spot, then you should stop looking and end the loop. Because right now, you would still keep looking for further spots and increase your counter. This is not intended.
2. You can omit one `int` variable, because you basically use both `i` and `autos` as a counter.
3. You can shorten the boolean check from `car.isDamaged() == true` to simply `car.isDamaged()`.
4. You can omit the boolean variable. By returning true / false directly instead of assigning to the variable first.